# Help me understand and fix this algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm

I wrote the following, but I'm not understanding it after modifying it some to fit with single pixels (graphic displays) instead of single characters (character displays).

XRES x YRES is the pixel resolution of each character. `LCDGraphic` draws its own characters based on these values. The idea in this transition algorithm is that you can go right, left, or (both) right one line, left the next line, then right, etc... The text version works like it's supposed to, but when I translated it for graphic displays, it's acting weird.

`LCOLS` is 256 (the sentinal), and `transition_tick_` increments till this sentinel each time `LCDGraphic::Transition()` is executed. `col` can thus be in the range between 0-255. Well, when pixels are going left and right, they're supposed to be moving together. However, for some reason the lines going right move till they're finished, then the lines moving left move till they're finished. It appears that where `col` is `< 128` the left moving lines are adjusting, then when `col` is `>= 128` the right moving lines adjust. I'm pretty well confused by this.

```
void LCDGraphic::Transition() {
    int direction = visitor_->GetDirection();
    int col;
    transitioning_ = true;
    for(unsigned int row = 0; row < LROWS / YRES; row++) {
        if( direction == TRANSITION_LEFT ||
            (direction == TRANSITION_BOTH && row % 2 == 0))
            col = LCOLS - transition_tick_;
        else if( direction == TRANSITION_RIGHT || direction == TRANSITION_BOTH)
            col = transition_tick_;
        else
            col = 0;

        if(col < 0)
            col = 0;

        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < YRES; i++) {
            int n = row * YRES * LCOLS + i * LCOLS;
            for(unsigned int l = 0; l < 1; l++) {// LAYERS; l++) {
                RGBA tmp[LCOLS];
                memcpy(tmp + XRES, GraphicFB[l] + n + col + XRES, (LCOLS - col) * sizeof(RGBA));
                for(unsigned j = 0; j < XRES; j++)
                        tmp[j] = NO_COL;
                memcpy(GraphicFB[l] + n + col, tmp, sizeof(RGBA) * (LCOLS - col));
            }
        }    
    }

    transition_tick_+=XRES;
    if( transition_tick_ >= (int)LCOLS ) {
        transitioning_ = false;
        transition_tick_ = 0;
        emit static_cast<LCDEvents *>(
            visitor_->GetWrapper())->_TransitionFinished();
    }

    GraphicBlit(0, 0, LROWS, LCOLS);
}
```

Comment: "I wrote the following, but I'm not understanding it" - how could you write it, if you don't understand it?

Comment: I first wrote it in Python where "lists" are very simple to deal with. I did luck out a little figuring it out. A little trial and error goes a long way.

Comment: What I never understood about it is why the first character is blank regardless if it's going right or left. Like I said, trial and error. I didn't expect it to do what it did, and when it just worked, I left it alone. I understand it a lot more now than I did then, but this particular issue confused me to no end. I still don't understand why it did this. It's my weakness as a programmer; I have dyscalculia, and some problems just go beyond me. I ruminate over problems, and eventually get them.

Comment: Your description of what this code is supposed to be doing may be clear to you, but it's very unclear to us. "The idea in this transition algorithm is that you can go right, left, or (both) right one line, left the next line, then right, etc..." *What?*

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Just half LCOLS. Odd problem though. I'm still a bit confused.

```
void LCDGraphic::Transition() {
    int direction = visitor_->GetDirection();
    int col;
    transitioning_ = true;
    for(unsigned int row = 0; row < LROWS / YRES; row++) {
        if( direction == TRANSITION_LEFT ||
            (direction == TRANSITION_BOTH && row % 2 == 0))
            col = LCOLS / 2 - transition_tick_; // changed this line
        else if( direction == TRANSITION_RIGHT || direction == TRANSITION_BOTH)
            col = transition_tick_;
        else
            col = 0;

        if(col < 0)
            col = 0;

        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < YRES; i++) {
            int n = row * YRES * LCOLS + i * LCOLS;
            for(unsigned int l = 0; l < 1; l++) {// LAYERS; l++) {
                RGBA tmp[LCOLS];
                LCDError("Transition: LROWS: %u, LCOLS: %u, n: %d, row: %d, col: %d, calc1: %d, calc2: %d, fb: %p, tmp: %p",
                    LROWS, LCOLS, n, row, col, n + col + XRES, (LCOLS - col) * sizeof(RGBA), GraphicFB, tmp);
                memcpy(tmp + XRES, GraphicFB[l] + n + col + XRES, (LCOLS - col) * sizeof(RGBA));
                for(unsigned j = 0; j < XRES; j++)
                        tmp[j] = NO_COL;
                memcpy(GraphicFB[l] + n + col, tmp, sizeof(RGBA) * (LCOLS - col));
            }
        }
    }

    transition_tick_+=XRES;
    if( transition_tick_ >= (int)LCOLS / 2) { //changed this line
        transitioning_ = false;
        transition_tick_ = 0;
        emit static_cast<LCDEvents *>(
            visitor_->GetWrapper())->_TransitionFinished();
    }

    GraphicBlit(0, 0, LROWS, LCOLS);
}
```